# Playing youtube videos on iOS the easiest working way

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube

Ok. I know this question has been asked many times before. BUT I can't seem to find a good, working, up to date answer. Some say "use the UIwebView" some say "use the MPMoviePlayer" some say it doesn't work, other says it does. There's talk about XCDYouTubeKit and HCYoutubeParser and other solutions but some seem to be out of date and others I can't get to work (but I am a beginner).

Can someone please clear this up!? What is the easiest working way to play a Youtube video in an iOS device. And can it be explained so that a beginner understands it? Please :)

I want to be able to play several Youtube videos in my app. When you press a button a specific video should **autoplay** in **fullscreen**, end when finished it should **return** to the app.

Answer (score 0):

XCDYouTubeKit should work fine and fulfills your requirements, i.e. autoplay in fullscreen and returns to the app when video playback finishes.

Here is how to use it:

```c
NSString *videoIdentifier = @"9bZkp7q19f0";
XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:videoIdentifier];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
```

If you can't get this to work please ask a new question with details on what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oxced. I tried to use the XCDYouTubeKit but I got stuck already on step 4 in the installation :S. It says; "Drag and drop the libXCDYouTubeKit.a file referenced from XCDYouTubeKit → Products...". I can't find the libXCDYouTubeKit.a-file anywhere (and there is no Products folder in the XCDYouTubeKet-folder!?). If you can help me to get this to work I will definitely donate som money your way :)

Comment: This [screenshot](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/95#issuecomment-63964710) should help you to find it. Another easy way to use XCDYouTubeKit is via [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org).

Comment: Thanks @0xced. I had to put this project aside for a while, but now I want to give it another try. I managed to install the XCDYouTubeKit thanks to the screenshot that you uploaded. But I’m having trouble understanding how to get it to work :(.  Where should I put the code and where should the URL be? And how do I connect that code with the button. Could you please explain so that a beginner understands it? Thank you and sorry for the trouble :(